# Can't access vtiger CRM

Tags: vtiger

I installed locally (windows 10) XAMPP V3.2.2, then vtiger 6.5.0 , I can not access the login form , I get this message:

> Invalid username or password.

I found no errors during installation and the data base MySql does not contain rows in vtiger_user table.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve using [TURNKEY/vtiger](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/vtiger)
choosing BUILDS VM for a virtual machine installed locally, it's vtiger CRM 6.3.0 not the last but useful for studying the product; in this mode, I have not encountered problems of access.

Answer (score 0):

You should check Vtiger Requirements
https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/System_Requirements

check SQL_MODE in MySQL(my.cnf/my.ini) 
SQL_MODE -> Should not have STRICT_TRANS_TABLE